# Is there a way to reuse components when deploying to the Sap Cloud Platform?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide, sap-cloud-platform

I am trying to reuse an application from another through the use of a ComponentContainer as demonstrated in this blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/10/23/demystifying-the-art-of-component-reuse-in-sapui5/

My application is being developed through the SAP Web IDE Full-Stack and is being deployed to the SAP Cloud Platform. I have seen examples of this working though deployment to the ABAP Repository but this is not what we are trying to do.

So far I have created a Child App and a Parent App and I am attempting to call the Child App from the Parent using a ComponentContainer. I have deployed the Child App but I am unsure as how to reference this app from the Parent.

This is my ParentApp view:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Parent.MyParentApp.controller.View1"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
<App id="idAppControl">
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <Text text="Hello"/>
                <core:ComponentContainer width="100%"
                    name="MyChildApp"
                    component="MyChildApp"/>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

ParentApp Component.js

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("MyChildApp", "/mychildapp/");
        jQuery.sap.require("MyChildApp.Component");
```

ParentApp neo-app.json

```
{
    "path": "/mychildapp/",
    "target":{
        "type": "application",
        "name": "mychildapp"
    },
    "description": "My Child App"
}
```

This is my ChildApp view:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="Child.MyChildApp.controller.View1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
<App id="idAppControl">
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <Text text="World"/>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Currently I am just getting the error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to load 'myChildApp/model/models.js' from ../../resources/myChildApp/model/models.js: 404 - ".

I am assuming the issue is to do with the paths given in the Component.js and neo-app.json but I am unsure what these paths need to be when working from the cloud platform.

I am quite new to Ui5 development so not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible, but any advice/help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is definately because of the wrong path. In order to find the correct path you could do the following:

1) open chrome DevTools and open the Network tab.

My guess is that the Component.js of your child-app will be colored in red, which means it wasn't loaded.
If you hover over the Component.js file of your **Parent** application, you'll be able to see the path where your Parent-application is stored. Hopefully if you adjust this path to a similar path, but for your Child-application, your reuse will work.

My guess is that the path of your Parent App Component will look like '/sap/fiori/parentApp/Component.js'.

If this is the case, try the following in the Component of your Parent application:

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("MyChildApp", "/sap/fiori/mychildapp");
```

Comment: Hi Kristoff, thanks for your reply. I ended up finding a slightly different solution to this. You were right it was the path that was incorrect, my issue was that the deployed version of the app had a slightly different name. So I just had to change the "/mychildapp/" to be the actual name of the deployed app. Also I was using an incorrect namespace, I should have been using "Child.MyChildApp".

Comment: glad you found a solution, if you can structure it maybe post it here so it can help other people aswell. Many people have to solve similar issues and I think those use cases are way too little documented